# Plone 5.0 and Carousel 2.2.1

Tags: carousel, plone

This question regards Plone 5.0 and add-on Carousel 2.2.1.  The version of Carousel, taken from /usr/local/Plone/buildout-cache/eggs/Products.Carousel-2.2.1-py2.7.egg/EGG-INFO, is:

```
Metadata-Version: 1.1
Name: Products.Carousel
Version: 2.2.1
Summary: Carousel allows you to add user-configurable rotating banners to any section of a Plone site.
Home-page: <https://github.com/collective/Products.Carousel>
Author: Groundwire
```

The following shows the results of attempting to start Plone in the foreground.  Plone started to a degree then crashed due to a problem with Carousel.  The beginning and end of the output are shown; lots of diagnostics in the middle of the output were elided.

```
root@wandboard # /bin/pwd; /bin/date; /usr/bin/sudo -u plone_daemon /usr/local/Plone/zinstance/bin/instance fg  
/usr/local/Plone-5.0/zinstance/var  
Sun Jan 10 18:35:19 EST 2016  
2016-01-10 18:35:28 INFO ZServer HTTP server started at Sun Jan 10 18:35:28 2016  
        Hostname: 0.0.0.0  
        Port: 8080  
2016-01-10 18:35:38 WARNING ZODB.blob (13658) Blob dir /usr/local/Plone-5.0/zinstance/var/blobstorage/ has insecure mode setting  
2016-01-10 18:35:57 INFO Plone OpenID system packages not installed, OpenID support not available  
Traceback (most recent call last):  
  File "/usr/local/Plone-5.0/zinstance/parts/instance/bin/interpreter", line 288, in <module>  
    exec(compile(`__file__f.read(), __file__, "exec")`)  
  File "/usr/local/Plone-5.0/buildout-cache/eggs/Zope2-2.13.23-py2.7.egg/Zope2/Startup/run.py", line 76, in <module>  
    run()  
  File "/usr/local/Plone-5.0/buildout-cache/eggs/Zope2-2.13.23-py2.7.egg/Zope2/Startup/run.py", line 22, in run  
    starter.prepare()  
   .  
   .  
   .  
   many more diagnostics elided  
   .  
   .  
   .  
  File "/usr/local/Plone-5.0/buildout-cache/eggs/zope.configuration-3.7.4-py2.7.egg/zope/configuration/fields.py", line 139, in fromUnicode  
    raise schema.ValidationError(v)  
zope.configuration.xmlconfig.ZopeXMLConfigurationError: File "/usr/local/Plone-5.0/zinstance/parts/instance/etc/site.zcml", line 16.2-16.23  
    ZopeXMLConfigurationError: File "/usr/local/Plone-5.0/buildout-cache/eggs/Products.Carousel-2.2.1-py2.7.egg/Products/Carousel/configure.zcml", line 23.2-23.32  
    ZopeXMLConfigurationError: File "/usr/local/Plone-5.0/buildout-cache/eggs/Products.Carousel-2.2.1-py2.7.egg/Products/Carousel/browser/configure.zcml", line 24.2-31.6  
    ConfigurationError: ('Invalid value for', 'class', 'ImportError: Module plone.app.layout.viewlets.common has no global ContentActionsViewlet')
```

In /usr/local/Plone-5.0/buildout-cache/eggs/Products.Carousel-2.2.1-py2.7.egg/Products/Carousel/browser/configure.zcml lines 24 to 31 are:

```
<browser:viewlet  
    name="plone.contentactions"  
    for="Products.Carousel.interfaces.ICarouselFolder"  
    view="..interfaces.ICarouselSettingsView"  
    manager="plone.app.layout.viewlets.interfaces.IContentViews"  
    class="plone.app.layout.viewlets.common.ContentActionsViewlet"  
    permission="zope2.View"  
    />
```

What is a ContentActionsViewlet?  Can I fix this by somehow installing a global ContentActionsViewlet or is this something the Carousel add-on authors would best be able to fix?  This same Carousel add-on works fine with Plone 4.3.2.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The addon is simply not Plone 5 compatible.

The `ContentActionsViewlet` was merged into the `ContentViewsViewlet` [See plone.app.layout 2.5.8](https://github.com/plone/plone.app.layout/blob/2.5.17/CHANGES.rst#258-2015-07-18)

Unfortunately this will not be the only issue.

You need to contact the maintainer, probably they are willing to upgrade the package, or you may try it by yourself:

- Plone 5 Uprade guide: http://docs.plone.org/develop/addons/upgrade_to_50.html
- Good example for package, which supports Plone 4.3.x and Plone 5 --> https://github.com/plone/plone.app.mosaic

Comment: Did the answer help?

Comment: Yes.  Unless the client requires upgrading to plone 5.x, I'll stick with Plone 4.3.x.

Comment: My case is to deal with diazotheme.plonecom + Products.Carousel (plone.com branch). For the record: at least also need to fix IContnetViews to IToolbar
https://github.com/plone/plone.app.layout/commit/a5c7d55aa59ed84240b17fa969cdd93a92abefdf#diff-bbaf38027f85fdf4c44b47bc73a5497e